# Questions answered in form not rendering in view in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm building an app that allows people to checkin with a teacher by simply filling out a form. I have users and the "checkins" I'm calling Pins. I've created the form but for some reason it's not rendering the answers that the user fills in.  Notice that the user email is showing up in the view but not any of the stuff entered in the form.

What am I doing wrong?

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@pin) do |f| %>
<% if @pin.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(@pin.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this pin from being saved:</h2>

  <ul>
  <% @pin.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
<% end %>

<div class="form-group">
<%= label_tag(:questions, "You can free-write anything you would like to share here, or you can     respond to one or more of the prompts below.") %>
 <%= f.text_field :questions, class: "form-control" %>
 </div>
<div class="form-group">
<%= label_tag(:questions, "You can write about your own actions or thoughts here.") %>
<%= f.text_area :questions, class: "form-control" %>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<%= label_tag(:questions, "You can write about the actions of another person here.") %>
<p>Please include the names of anyone that was there</p>
<%= f.text_area :questions, class: "form-control" %>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<%= label_tag(:questions, "If you have a question, comment, or message for your teacher, please  write it here.") %>
 <%= f.text_area :questions, class: "form-control" %>
 </div>
<div class="form-group">
<%= label_tag(:questions, "Are you considering another action? You can write about it here.") %>
<%= f.text_area :questions, class: "form-control" %>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<%= f.submit "submit", class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

show.html

```
p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
<strong>Description:</strong>

<%= @pin.questions %>
</p>

<% if @pin.user == current_user %>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_pin_path(@pin) %>
<% end %>
<%= link_to 'Back', pins_path %>
```

index.html.erb for pins (checkin)

```
  <h1>All your checkins are listed below</h1>

  <h3>Checkin</h3>



     <% @pins.each do |pin| %>

    <p><%= pin.questions %></p>
    <p><%= pin.user.email if pin.user %></p>
    <%= link_to 'Show', pin %>
    <% if pin.user == current_user %>
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_pin_path(pin) %>
    <%= link_to 'Destroy', pin, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
    <% end %>

   <% end %>

   <br>

  <% if user_signed_in? %>
  <%= link_to 'New Checkin', new_pin_path %>
  <% end %>
```

Schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20141219162930) do

create_table "pins", force: true do |t|
t.string   "description"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.text     "questions"
t.integer  "user_id"
end

add_index "pins", ["user_id"], name: "index_pins_on_user_id"

create_table "users", force: true do |t|
t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
t.string   "reset_password_token"
t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
t.datetime "remember_created_at"
t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
end

add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique:    true

end
```

EDIT:

Here is my pins controller. I pretty sure I'm not whitlisting the params' correctly. If someone knows the proper way please share.

```
class PinsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_pin, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

def index
@pins = Pin.all
end

def show
end

  def new
  @pin = current_user.pins.build
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
   @pin = current_user.pins.build(pin_params)
   if @pin.save
  redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Checkin was successfully created.'
  else
  render action: 'new'
  end
  end

  def update
  if @pin.update(pin_params)
  redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Checkin was successfully updated.'
  else
  render action: 'edit'
 end
 end

def destroy
@pin.destroy
redirect_to pins_url
end

private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_pin
  @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
end

def correct_user
  @pin = current_user.pins.find_by(id: params[:id])
  redirect_to pins_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this pin" if @pin.nil?
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def pin_params
  params.require(:questions),permit(:id,:user_id,:questions)
end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of rails are you using? If it's rails 4, have you whitelisted the params for the pins in your controller? http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html

Comment: I think you are right. I added my controller to the question above. I've made some edits to it but am getting a syntax error. What's the best way for me to write this?

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. in my pins controller I had to add this line def pin_params
      params.require(:pin).permit(:question)
    end